# Magento sales/order_item_collection showing same order multiple times

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order

The Magento sales/order_item_collection is showing the same order multiple times,

```
$salesCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_item_collection')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from' => $from, 'to' => $to))
        ->load();

    foreach($salesCollection as $order){
        if(!empty($order)){
         // my order details ...
        }
    }
```

This is what im getting after printing the following methods

```
getIncrementId() - getOrderId() - getId() - getStatus()

100001519-1519-5083-Ordered
100001519-1519-5084-Ordered
100001519-1519-5085-Ordered
100001519-1519-5086-Ordered
100001519-1519-5087-Ordered
100001519-1519-5088-Ordered
100001519-1519-5089-Ordered
100001519-1519-5090-Ordered
100001519-1519-5091-Ordered
100001519-1519-5092-Ordered
100001519-1519-5093-Ordered
100001520-1520-5094-Ordered
100001520-1520-5095-Ordered
100001520-1520-5096-Ordered
100001520-1520-5097-Ordered
100001520-1520-5098-Ordered
100001520-1520-5099-Ordered
```

What i noticed is the order #100001519 has 11 items & #100001520 has 6 items. Is there anything wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 0):

add another filter to collection:

`addAttributeToFilter('parent_id',0)` and will proper items listing

Comment: Im getting an error when i tried to filter the collection with parent_id : Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'parent_id' in 'where clause'